# White space between menu bar and parallax banner (Rails App)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing an application in ruby on rails and bootstrap, my problem is a blank space appears between the menu and banner.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

application.css.scss

```
@import "jquery-ui";
@import "normalize-rails";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-material-design";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "ripples";
@import "footer";

$border-hover-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

* {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
  position: relative;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
}

.banner-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(/assets/bird-bg.jpg);
  background-size: auto 600px;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Code of application.html.erb in Rails

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=devise-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Simple IN</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
  <body>
    <% if notice %>
      <div id="message_wrapper">
        <p class="notice"><strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong> <%= notice %></p>
      </div>
    <% elsif alert %>
      <div id="message_wrapper">
        <p class="alert"><strong>¡Ocurrió un problema!</strong> <%= alert %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= render 'shared/nav' %>
    <div class=""">
      <%= yield %>  <---- (page#index banner)
    </div>
    <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

nav.html.erb

```
<div class="navbar navbar-warning">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-warning-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Simple IN</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-warning-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <% if(!user_signed_in?) %>
              <li><%= link_to new_user_session_path do %>
                  <i class="material-icons right">keyboard_arrow_right</i> Ingresar
                  <% end %>
              </li>
            <% else %>
              <li><%= link_to new_user_session_path do %>
                    <i class="material-icons right">sms</i> Mensajes
                  <% end %>
              </li>
              <li><%= link_to new_user_session_path do %>
                    <i class="material-icons right">live_help</i> Ayuda
                  <% end %>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="bootstrap-elements.html" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><%= avatar_for(current_user, size: 25) %> <%= current_user.name %>
                    <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><%= link_to 'Dashboard', dashboards_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to 'Editar Perfil', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><%= link_to 'Cerrar sesión', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

View Index.html.erb of Page controller

```
<div class="banner-box">

</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="banner-small-box">

</div>
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: it's hard to help you without a link to the page or example with jsfiddle.net

Comment: My question is, ¿who is I have to add the CSS to remove the white line between the menu bar and the picture? thanks for answering

Comment: I understood your question.. but If you want an answer, you should provide a working example, or at least post your full code here

Comment: Go to chrome. Right click on white space, then click inspect. Play around with the element inspector and the CSS properties attached to each element and you can figure it out that way

Comment: before the banner you have extra `"` in this code `class="""` try to remove it

Comment: thank you very much for your help, was a beginer mistake in css! :)

Comment: The solution .navbar { margin-bottom: 0; } in application.css.scss